# How to use DisposableObserver with lambda expressions in RxJava2

Tags: android, lambda, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

My use case in is want to dispose after a certain condition in my onNext. So trying to use DisposableObserver. This is the code that works

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                       System.out.println("onNext() received: " + integer);
                       if (integer == 2) {
                         dispose();
                       }
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onError(Throwable e) { System.out.println("onError()"); }
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete() { System.out.println("onComplete()"); }
                   }
    );
```

Now if you try to replace this with lambda it treats the lambda as

```
subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError,Action onComplete)
```

Doing it this way for now. By saving the disposable from onSubscribe and then calling disposable.dispose(); from onNext.

```
  private Disposable disposable;
  private void disposableObserverTest() {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .subscribe(integer -> {
              System.out.println("onNext() received: " + integer);
              if (integer == 2) {
                disposable.dispose();
              }

            }, throwable -> System.out.println("error"),
            () -> System.out.println("complete"),
            disposable1 -> {
              this.disposable = disposable1;
            });
  }
```

However, if you want to call dispose() directly how to do it with lambdas?

Comment: "This gives an error" - of what kind?

Comment: The error is it won't find dispose() as it treats the lambda as 
Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError,
            Action onComplete.

But I want the lambda to be a DisposableObserver.

Answer (score 4):

you can use takeUntil to close the observable.

```
@Test
public void takeUntil() throws Exception {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .takeUntil(integer -> integer == 2)
            .test()
            .assertValues(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because in the first case you call

```
subscribe(DisposableObserver observer)
```

while in the second case you call

```
subscribe(Action1<? extends Integer> onNext, Action1<? extends Throwable> onError, Action0 onComplete)
```

That means in the second case you don't hold reference to the `DisposableObserver` and therefore you can't call `dispose()` on it.

Comment: Exactly the problem. So I want to use DisposableObserver with lambdas in my second case.